# AWS - How to restrict the user to delete or modify the lambda function created by others

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I need to add a new AWS user to use lambda function, but I don't want him to delete or modify the lambda functions created by the other users. If I can also not show the other existing lambda functions to him, it will be the most ideal solution. How should I set up this in IAM policy?

Answer (score 1):

As per [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/granular-access-lambda/), you'll want an IAM policy similar to the following. Replace the relevant AWS values.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PermissionToInvoke",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:AWS_REGION:AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:function:LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just in case AWS has announced something new, do you have a link to AWS IAM Lambda Resources at the function name level?

Comment: I have seen their docs continue to say that you can't use resource-level permissions, but I believe those are in error. You can see the definitive answer in the table entry for `Invoke` under the Resource column in [Lambda API Permissions: Actions, Resources, and Conditions Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-api-permissions-ref.html). I have also used these permissions in projects lately.

Comment: Specifically [Using Identity-Based Policies (IAM Policies) for AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html) in [Step 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-identity-based.html#console-permissions-invoke) seems to continue to imply that you should use the wildcard. Of course AWS could be of the opinion that wildcard works also. I do think this misleads people. There may be other cases.

Comment: Lambda Function Names are now listed on the ARNs and Name Space document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html.

Comment: @dmulter Sorry that I may not make the question very clear. I would like to make each user can only modify the lambda function he/she created. The only thing I can think about your solution is that I will need to create the function first and then assign that to the user. Am I correct?

Comment: @simonhb1990 You can of course add any actions you like to the policy based on what you want to permit. Sounds like you want `DeleteFunction` and `UpdateFunctionCode` at a minimum. You can see what other actions are permitted per function from the [Lambda API Permissions: Actions, Resources, and Conditions Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-api-permissions-ref.html) I had linked above. You can create the policy before the function without a problem.